# Methods for irregular time series data

Tags: time-series, python, forecasting

I have a dataset that looks like this.

```
Month    Name Class   GPA
1/1/2020 Anna Math    3.2
1/2/2020 Anna Phil    3.1
1/4/2020 Anna Math    3.0
1/5/2020 Anna Math    3.4
1/7/2020 Anna Phil    3.5
```

I want to use this data to forecast GPA for the next few months. So the desired result will look like this. In the actual dataset, I have many more people and classes.

For every “combination” of the categorical variables (Name and Class), I would like a forecast value of the GPA on a monthly basis.

```
Month    Name Class  GPA
1/8/2020 Anna Math   3.2
1/9/2020 Anna Phil   3.1
1/8/2020 Anna Math   3.0
1/9/2020 Anna Math   3.4
```

The time frequency is Month, however as you can see… the data is irregular and we don’t have records for every month.

I want to do this forecasting in python. What is the best model to use for this type of data and what sort of preprocessing should be done?

Any guidance and references would be appreciated.